# Delete all the digits in the string using Regex, python

Tags: regex, string, python-3.x

I am new to regex. I am trying to remove all digits but digits corresponding to response should remain as is in the whole string and rest of the digits should be removed. For example 892 and 762 corresponding to response should be remain as it is in the string and whenever these values occurs again in the string should NOT be removed. But rest other digits should be removed.

```
mystr=" hey vi_pl12879 remove all the digits
        am_87284 remove all the digits except res value
        how are you response > 892
        omh 8241 del the digits 
        delete the manm/alka/8726/uh/the
        the code for error is 892
        response > 762
        keep only res values in the whole string
        error code may be 762"
```

Expected Result:

```
mystr=" hey vi_ remove all the digits
        am_ remove all the digits except res value
        how are you response > 892
        omh  del the digits 
        delete the manm/alka//uh/the
        the code for error is 892
        response > 762
        keep only res values in the whole string
        error code may be 762"
```

Comment: You asked to remove digits but this input `vi_pl12879` changed to `vi_`. So some letters are deleted too. Is that correct?

Comment: Also, could you clarify the rules for keeping the numbers. For example: `keep all numbers after "response >"`

Comment: @l'-'l, I have updated the question please have a look. Response won't be always 3 digits. It can be more too.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a positive lookup ahead to remove all digits but digits which are after the first `response >` expression which you can find out using `findall`:

```
import re

mystr=" hey vi_pl12879 remove all the digits\
 am_87284 remove all the digits except res value\
 how are you response > 892\
 omh 8241 del the digits\
 delete the manm/alka/8726/uh/the\
 the code for error is 892\
 response > 762\
 keep only res values in the whole string\
 error code may be 762"

response_groups = re.findall(r".+?(response > \d+)", mystr)

res = re.sub(
    r"\d(?=.+?" + response_groups[0] + ")",
    "",
    mystr
)

print(res)
```

This prints:

> hey vi_pl remove all the digits am_ remove all the digits except res value how are you response > 892 omh 8241 del the digits delete the manm/alka/8726/uh/the the code for error is 892 response > 762 keep only res values in the whole string error code may be 762

Comment: Thanks what does response > 8 doing?

Comment: @user15051990 the regular expression engine will find all numbers before `response > 8`. After that expression it will not find any more numbers.

Comment: But 8 will always not be the case. Right? Is there any some generic solution to the problem. And I want to remove all the digits other than  response numbers.

Comment: @user15051990 Yes, you have a point there.

Comment: Thanks for solution. Could you please help in getting the more generic one?

Comment: @user15051990 I have tried to find the first `response > \d` expression and then include it into the regular expression. This makes it more generic, but requires two steps.

Comment: Thank you so much. I have edited the question to make it more clear.